# JavaScript changed DOM value not working in JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that is changing some parameters dynamically based on activities on the page. The function for replacing the values seems to be working fine and I can see in the "elements" window in the chrome developer tools that it is being updated. However, when I try to read that value from another JS function, then it is as it has not been changed at all.

I have made a very simplified example of the issue:

```
<a href="#" id="a-delete-page" data-action="data/1/pageid/0/">
check data-action value</a>    
<a href="#" id="toggle">set new value</a>

<script>
$('#a-delete-page').click(test);
$('#toggle').click(toggleValue);

function toggleValue(){
    var newValue = '123';    
    $("#a-delete-page").attr('data-action',newValue);

    alert("new value set:"+newValue);  
}

function test(){
  alert($(this).data('action'));   
}
</script>
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hj3e/

First click "check data-action value" and you see the data-action parameter. Then click set new value (and you see it changes in the developer tool) and click "check data-action value" again. I would expect it to print 123, but it still prints "data/1/pageid/0/".

Could anyone help me understand this and also direct me on how to resolve this.

Comment: data object and data attribute is not the same thing. Only that jQuery on DOM load will parse data-* attributes to data object, but changing then data-* attribute will not update data object, see jsFiddle to fix your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2hj3e/1/

Comment: It doesn't happen on DOM load, it happens the first time you call `.data()` on an element. In his jsfiddle, that happens when it calls `updateUrlParameter` with the old data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery only pulls in the values from the `data-` attributes the first time that you call `.data()`. After that, it essentially caches them, so even if you update or add another `data-` attribute, it doesn't get reflected in calls to `.data()`. If you want to update the data after that initial call, then you need to use `.data('action', newvalue)` to set it.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has some quirks with `.data`. If you are using `.data` to retrieve the value, also use it to set it.

```
$("#a-delete-page").data('action',newValue);
```

Comment: could it be that it's setting an object's property instead of the actual element attribute?  I too noticed that setting data via jQuery doesn't update the document element with a `data-` attribute.

Comment: I think the problem was that attributes can only contain strings, and `.data` can contain an arbitrary object.

Comment: Good to know! you don't have any documentation on this other than api.jquery.com do you?

Comment: No, that's probably where I've got it from.